# Can we bookmark an answer instead of a question?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, answers, bookmarks

I've come across [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14110189/381149) that is not the most upvoted nor the accepted answer but which I personally find the best. This post has quite numerous long answers and I would like to somehow bookmark the answer I'm interested in, just like I can bookmark a question. Is there a way to do it?

If not, do you think this can be useful and I should suggest a new feature?

Comment: Browser bookmark would work well. Adding a new feature like this may not provide much value. Note: I have not yet casted my vote on your question yet :)

Comment: @AzizShaikh yes but bookmarks will not alert you where there is modification,  and I was thinking to use my favorite tab as an easy way to refer to usefull answers ...

Comment: @iStimple well I was thinking of a personal flag, not to be seen by other users

Comment: MSE posts: [Mark answer as favorite/star](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2588/mark-answer-as-favorite-star) and [Is there any way to favorite/bookmark an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1569/is-there-any-way-to-favorite-bookmark-an-answer)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Bookmarking the question is always better than bookmarking an individual answer.

How can you be sure that someone else won't come along and post an *even better* answer to the question? Of course, you can't! In fact, you can almost bet that they will, since that's the whole model of Stack Exchange.

And if this happened under your proposed approach, you'd completely miss that new and improved answer because you'd only bookmarked the one that was currently there. Had you bookmarked the question, on the other hand, you'd see the new answer and the community's assessment of its quality/helpfulness.

Once you've got the question in your bookmarks list, you can easily return to it and find all of the answers. Your "favorite" answer will be clearly marked by the glowing orange upvote arrow. :-)

Comment: you are right on that point, it was just to save some time reading the entire thread, searching for the "hidden gem"

Comment: Well, I just look for the orange upvote arrow to find my favorite answers. :-)

Comment: That is as good as it gets know. You made a good point about the time component. Will redraw my answer.

Comment: but if I upvote more than one answer, and still think one of them is the best between them all? I upvoted many as I think they add good information, but I will actually mainly/only use the information of the best one IMO. Without the favorited answer, I will have to lose time tracking again wich one was the best one. Even if there are new good answers, I may not have the time for that. [link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342394/my-private-personal-accepted-answer-discussion)

Comment: One extreme case that I came out is that there are some hacky answers that are getting more down votes than up votes, however sometimes hacky answers are still useful. Then, if someone has low reputation such that they are not able to view the closed answers, what should they do if they still in favor of the hacky answers.

Answer (score 15):

I like the logic presented in [Cody Gray's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269818) but it fails to address why one would want to favorite an answer.  There are various reasons to favorite a question, some are the same with answers, some are not.  Cody Gray makes the argument that additional answers may supersede a favorite one in the future.  And this is true.  But answers themselves can be interesting for their content and not necessarily for the answer they provide.

One example would be if I find an answer to a question like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47686400).  I'm not interested in multi-paged matrices, but the answer given here is unique and interesting to me.  I want to take time and learn more about it.  In fact my desire to remember this answer led me to search for a way to favorite an answer.  I care very little about future answers to this question so to favorite the question makes little sense.  I think it would be a useful feature to add.

My favorite question list is, at it's core, a collection of answers I like to remember.  Why not have a list of favorite answers directly.

Answer (score 4):

With the launch of the [Saves feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves) recently, you are now able to save answers! As such, I've added the [status-completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) label.

Answer (score 3):

Why allow marking an answer as favorite?

- What constitutes 'best' is subjective. If we follow the 'safety in numbers' principle, the community is always right. However, it is not that simple. Oftentimes, multiple
  solutions are posted which all seem to work for different groups of
  people. In such a case, I wouldn't call the most upvoted answer the
  'best' answer. It is simply the solution that seems to have worked
  for the largest group of people.
- I often upvote multiple answers that all have been helpful in some way. Looking through my upvoted answers to a question only marginally helps me find that answer that made a lot of sense a couple of years ago.
- We already have favorite questions. It makes sense to allow favorite answers. Granted: both are very subjective.