# Save Answers to Your Own Snippet Library

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bookmarks, code

This comes from the meta topic [Can we favorite an answer instead of a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269814/can-we-favorite-an-answer-instead-of-a-question)

Where the accepted answer was that we could not "favorite an answer" but you can find it by looking for your upvote.

As an improvement to this as you may have upvoted many answers, could we have a facility to mark an answer as a code snippet so that we can easily find it again if we found it useful.

I recently came across a question where a not accepted answer was really useful to me and I would have to copy and paste it to my own snippet library or risk losing where I found it amongst all the other questions/answers.

Having access to these snippets would keep people coming back to SO to find the snippet (keeps the advertisers happy) and also allows for continual improvement of said answer as technology changes (keeps everyone happy)

To clarify - this is not related to [Stack Snippets](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). I use the term snippet to signify a block of reusable code that you can insert where you need it in your own code.

Comment: Can you clarify this please? Is this something to do with Stack Snippets? Or just some way of marking favourite answers?

Comment: Why limit it to code-based answers?

Comment: I know I've seen someone ask for this before but I can't remember how they referred to it.

Comment: We can already mark a question as a favourite. On many questions my favourite answer is not the accepted or the top answer. It would be nice to have a list of my "favourite answers" held by Stackoverflow, almost the same as the current list of favourite questions but referring to answers.

Comment: In most browsers, there is a little star / book thingy in or around the address bar somewhere. If you follow the `share` link below the post then click that icon, it will "bookmark" that answer for later. Then you can go back to those exact answers later on. You can usually even name those "bookmarks" so that you can find them easier in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a major flaw in your feature request: if the proposal for a favorite answer is declined, why try it with a subset which is eventually less useful. Also, what use does a library of code have without he explanation? The last thing is what makes SO special and worth the time.