# Why no ability to star answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

Context: I've personally have seen answers that I want to have the ability to star.

If there is an answer that has a need to be bookmarked, but the question has none, you'd like to star the answer instead of the question. Why not a small "star" link below each answer?

Is there any reason we don't have the ability to star answers?

EDIT: Because sometimes the question is years old and there won't be new answers at all. Maybe your busy implementing it and you're checking back to remember how. You also don't want to star (like in the duplicate question) a normal question and make the asker think he/she's such a good question but its really because you want a bookmark to the answer.

Comment: And otherwise: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269814/can-we-favorite-an-answer-instead-of-a-question

Comment: @Bart, well I guess I would have to just copy the answer link to my bookmarks instead of being able to find it in my 'starred' link.