# Make it possible to bookmark *answers*

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, answers, bookmarks

Stack Overflow already allows bookmarking a question.
It'll be really nice if we could **bookmark specific answers**. It can save a lot of time, especially when you're trying to find something specific (which was maybe not marked as the correct answer for a question but works for you).

I tend to save "answer links" in a notes app and refer back to them when needed. Having a system on the site itself would save lots of time and allow us to find things faster.

Comment: Related (MSE): [Is there any way to favorite/bookmark an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1569/is-there-any-way-to-favorite-bookmark-an-answer)

Comment: If a notes thingy works for you, why not use the browser bookmarking system then?

Comment: See [Can we favorite an answer instead of a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269814/215552)

Comment: You can do all the same actions to an answer as you can a question, eg. share, edit, follow, flag, comment, vote, view edit history.. all *except* bookmark it. The imbalance of that one feature omission continues to strike me as strange.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319449/253521

Comment: @Gimby The notes thing doesn't exactly work for me since the searching is quite cumbersome (you have to label the links or write some info along with the link to make it searchable). The same issue is there with browser bookmarks. Having this feature on the site itself would just make things really convenient

Comment: I find it useful when the answer you're interested is far away from the top of the list of a bundle of answers.

Comment: Somewhat related: *[Sunsets are often memorable - could we have a tag for deprecated features?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382600/sunsets-are-often-memorable-could-we-have-a-tag-for-deprecated-features)*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Now it is possible to bookmark (or "save") an answer. As you can see in the below attached screenshot, there is an option to bookmark the answer:

[image]

See this announcement for more details: [Bookmarks have evolved into Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves)

Answer (score 18):

It's not exactly the same thing, but you can "Follow" answers:

[image]

And then find them later by going to your profile:

[image]

Disadvantages:

- You'll also get an inbox message when there's activity on the answer
- Your Following tab may contain other posts you intended to just *follow* to track activity, but not for the purpose of bookmarking