# Suggestion for bookmark answers in addition to questions

Tags: feature-request, answers, bookmarks

I saw someone has answered a question similar to mine:

> Bookmarking the question is always better than bookmarking an individual answer.
>
> (from: [Cody Gray's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269818/18991903))

But my suggestion has somehow deviated from some of the other similar questions/suggestions: **I want to bookmark one or multiple answers to a question that has many answers (some popular ones may have over 100 answers).** Because it is so difficult to find back the answer I want. Although I could make a note/use bookmark from the browser, It is still difficult when I forget where it is. However, when having a centralised place, it will be much easier to find. Especially with custom grouping.

Comment: See [this Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1569/is-there-any-way-to-favorite-bookmark-an-answer) and [this one that's status declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2588/mark-answer-as-favorite-star)